# Can't drag files to Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am having an unusual problem. I have always been able to drag files and folder from my desktop or explorer to the solution explorer in visual studio and add the files to my project. No when I attempt to drag files I simply get the "stop" symbol.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 running on Vista Home Premium 64 bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: I experience the same behavior on Vista 64 Ultimate and VS 2008 though TBH I've never added files this way.

Comment: I just moved from Server 2008 (as a desktop) to Win7 x64 Ultimate and am now experiencing this same problem. I run VS2008 as Admin and have also tried running Explorer as Admin and Standard but no luck so far.

Comment: Looks like this is also being discussed on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/59051/

Answer (score 43):

Windows will not let you drag from one window to another if only one of those windows is running as Administrator.

Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

**In short :** Run Visual Studio as **Non Administrator**.

Comment: They really should display a message explaining why drag and drop is broken when you attempt it

Comment: It didn't work when I ran both VS and Explorer as Administrator either. Only worked with both running as a non-Administrator.

Comment: it randomly lets you do and sometimes does not. both as admin and non admin.

Comment: For me, it didn't work when they were both set as Administrator and DID work when I set them both as non-Administrator.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this when your project is running. Is it?

Comment: No. The project is not running nor am I compiling.

Answer (score 3):

I also cannot drop files from the explorer onto Visual Studio when it is running in admin mode.

But please try opening 'Add / Existing Item ... ' from the Solution Explorer / Manager context menu in Visual Studio and drag and drop files and folders from that window.

Works on my machine with Visual Studio 2012 ...

Comment: Excellent workaround! Works for me on Windows 8.1 with VS 2012, running as admin.

Comment: This should be higher. While yes you probably shouldn't run VS as Administrator if possible the top answer doesn't actually answer the question, this one does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and noticed I was pulling files from a folder that was compressed. I unzipped all the files and was able to drag and drop into the solutions explorer fine. Make sure your files are not in view mode in a compressed folder.