# Why is it no longer possible to drag files to solution explorer in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In VS2010 I could always drag files to the solution explorer. This no longer works in Visual Studio 2012. How can I enable this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Can't drag files to Solution Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267323/cant-drag-files-to-solution-explorer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a Windows 'feature' as I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275227/106866):

> Windows will not let you drag from one window to another if only one
>   of those windows is running as Administrator.
>
> Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?