# Drag & Drop files into Visual Studio doesn't work

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

shortly I made a fresh install of Windows 8.1 on my computer. Since that I'm having trouble when dragging files from Explorer or TotalCommander into Visual Studio - it doesn't work *most* of the time. It does work - but only when I closed all open documents in Visual Studio (it's not necessary to close the currently open solution, just the open source files).

I read that it may be a rights problem, but I'm sure this isn't the case on my computer because I have disabled UAC and - as I mentioned - drag & drop works when there is no open document.

What could be the cause of this problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 11):

Just figured this myself (it's really annoying)

It is caused because the Administrator account status is disabled by default and all administrators run in Admin Approval mode.

In order to get it working open control panel, administrative tools, local security policy and under security change **Accounts: Administrator account status** to enabled and **UAC: Run all admins in Admin Approval Mode** to disabled.

Comment: Great you figured it out!
I'm a Windows 8 Home User and unfortunately don't have the Local Security Policy Editor. Can someone please tell me which registry keys I have to set?

Comment: P E R F E C T answer !

Comment: Its Control Panel => Administrative Tools => Local Security Policy and under Security Settings => Local Policies => Secucity Options change Accounts: Administrator account status to enabled and UAC: Run all admins in Admin Approval Mode to disabled.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 8 (actually using 8.1) you can do it via UI located:

- Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy
- Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options

  - Accounts: Administrator account status = Enabled
  - UAC: Run all admins in Admin Approval Mode = Disabled

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 8 Home

Regedit.exe

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA

Set value to 0

Reboot