# cmake: how to create visual studio filters

Tags: visual-studio, filter, cmake

I have already looked around (StackOverflow and more) and I'm trying to use cmake to generate Visual Studio filters. I have the following folders:

```
src/math  
src/import  
src/ui
```

I would like to generate the filters like above.
`math`: contains all the cpp & h files in src/math
`import`: contains all the cpp & h files in src/import
`ui`: contains all the cpp & h files in src/ui

I have tried several solutions, but none seems to work!!!

Here is the last version of the code in `CMakeList.txt`:

```
set(VD_SRC "${VisualDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/src/visualdesigner")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_UI
    "${VD_SRC}/ui/*.cpp", "${VD_SRC}/ui/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_IMPORT
    "${VD_SRC}/import/*.cpp",
    "${VD_SRC}/import/*.h")

source_group("ui"            FILES ${SRC_UI})
source_group("import"        FILES ${SRC_IMPORT})
```

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: I suppose you want to get a target for the files? Or what do you mean with filters? Is this something Visual Studio specific?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio has some kind of "folder" in the "solution", they call this "filter". It allow to organise all the files like the folders in VS !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

See [How to set Visual Studio Filters for nested sub directory using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422680/how-to-set-visual-studio-filters-for-nested-sub-directory-using-cmake)

Just be aware that

- the [`source_group()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/source_group.html) command only works in combination with [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html) or [`add_executable()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_executable.html) commands listing the same sources (the paths must match)
- the `source_group()` command does not check if the file actually exists (so it takes anything you give it and during project file generation it tries to match the given source group file names against files used in the project)

I have given your code a try by adding a corresponding `add_library()` target and it works as expected (CMake 3.3.2 and VS2015):

```
set(VD_SRC "${VisualDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/src/visualdesigner")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_UI
    "${VD_SRC}/ui/*.cpp"
    "${VD_SRC}/ui/*.h"
)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_IMPORT
    "${VD_SRC}/import/*.cpp"
    "${VD_SRC}/import/*.h"
)

add_library(VisalDesigner ${SRC_UI} ${SRC_IMPORT})

source_group("ui"            FILES ${SRC_UI})
source_group("import"        FILES ${SRC_IMPORT})
```

Results in

[image: Solution Explorer with Filters]

Here is a more generalized version taken from [Visual Studio as an editor for CMake friendly project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645217/visual-studio-as-an-editor-for-cmake-friendly-project):

```
set(_src_root_path "${VisualDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/src/visualdesigner")
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE _source_list 
    LIST_DIRECTORIES false
    "${_src_root_path}/*.c*"
    "${_src_root_path}/*.h*"
)

add_library(VisualDesigner ${_source_list})

foreach(_source IN ITEMS ${_source_list})
    get_filename_component(_source_path "${_source}" PATH)
    file(RELATIVE_PATH _source_path_rel "${_src_root_path}" "${_source_path}")
    string(REPLACE "/" "\\" _group_path "${_source_path_rel}")
    source_group("${_group_path}" FILES "${_source}")
endforeach()
```

Answer (score 4):

I found it easier to do this and thought it might be helpful to others. Make sure you are using the latest version of CMAKE.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE _source_list *.cpp* *.h* *.hpp*)
foreach(_source IN ITEMS ${_source_list})
    get_filename_component(_source_path "${_source}" PATH)
    string(REPLACE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" "" _group_path "${_source_path}")
    string(REPLACE "/" "\\" _group_path "${_group_path}")
    source_group("${_group_path}" FILES "${_source}")
endforeach()
```

Comment: This works really well! I used it with Visual Studio 2017 and CMake 3.8

Comment: Using cmake 3.14.1 and Visual Studio 2019, this worked, _except I had to add the headers to `add_exectuable` or `add_library`_. If I didn't do that, only the .cpp files showed up in the filters/VS project. I couldn't find anything about this in the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/source_group.html).  Maybe a bug or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

As of CMake [3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/source_group.html), the `source_group` command offers a `TREE` argument to recursively search the files paths of your sources to structure the source groups to match your file system structure. Now, the solution is a *lot* cleaner, no need for looping:

```
set(VD_SRC "${VisualDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/src/visualdesigner")
file(GLOB_RECURSE UI_IMPORT_MATH_SRCS
    "${VD_SRC}/ui/*.cpp"
    "${VD_SRC}/ui/*.h"
    "${VD_SRC}/import/*.cpp"
    "${VD_SRC}/import/*.h"
    "${VD_SRC}/math/*.cpp"
    "${VD_SRC}/math/*.h"
)

add_library(VisualDesigner ${UI_IMPORT_MATH_SRCS})

# Create the source groups for source tree with root at VD_SRC.
source_group(TREE ${VD_SRC} FILES ${UI_IMPORT_MATH_SRCS})
```

Also, check out the new `PREFIX` argument you can use with [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/source_group.html) if you find that useful.

**Disclaimer**: I advise against the use of `GLOB` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil)) wherever possible.

Comment: With CMake 3.8, `source_group` with `TREE` [does not place the files that are at the "root" of the src into the "root" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564143/how-can-i-cleanly-place-files-in-the-root-filter-in-visual-studio-using-cmake), it places them in `Source Files` and `Header Files` filters. I have yet to find a way to get this done "cleanly".

Answer (score 2):

For those, who want to create them under "Header Files" and "Source Files":

You can use [source_group](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html). Here's a concrete example.

Suppose you have a directory structure like:

```
|-include
    | some.h
    |-sub
       | someother.h 
|-src
   | some.cpp
   |-sub
      |-someother.cpp
```

Collect the files (some people - including the documentation - discourages use of GLOB, but I leave that to you, you can list of them one by if you want to, though I find GLOB is just fine many times):

```
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES_SUB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sub/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES_SUB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sub/*.h")

# Setup your library or executable:
add_library(MY_LIB ${HEADER_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES_SUB}
                   ${SOURCE_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES_SUB})

# Here's the important part ("Header Files" and "Source Files" are literals.)
source_group("Header Files\\sub" ${HEADER_FILES_SUB})
source_group("Source Files\\sub" ${SOURCE_FILES_SUB})
```

Comment: The solution proposed by @swdon is the most correct and easiest one - the previous ones did NOT work for me.

Comment: I think you're missing `FILES` for `source_group("Header Files\\sub" FILES ${HEADER_FILES_SUB})`

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers work in general. If you have multiple library targets and wish to create fancy filters for each of the `targets`, then you need to be a bit careful.

After quite a lot of headbanging, I figured you should keep the `source_group` call in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file where you did an `add_library(target ..)` or `add_executable(target ..)`. You can cache (internal) the "source\header lists" anywhere and use it here.