# how to put a file in a folder in Visual Studio with cmake

Tags: cmake

With cmake, we can put several targets in a user-defined folder within the Visual Studio project. For example:

[image]

This can be down with `source_group` command of cmake. So here is my question: how can I put a file within this folder. IN thisexample, how can I put readme.txt insider the modules folder, and make it parallel with targets such as opencv_core? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this in the past with CMake 2.8.12. You can't, it would have to be generated into your solution. Maybe newer versions of CMake does support it (haven't tried it).

Comment: Checked with the latest version, you can't. The code for this is just not there. You would need some code outputting `ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject`|`EndProjectSection` sections in e.g. [`cmGlobalVisualStudio71Generator::WriteSLNFile()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/7d2a0aa76c25d92f1e2a03778f5666bdd7e56b92/Source/cmGlobalVisualStudio71Generator.cxx#L79)

Comment: "_Folders_" in Visual Studio solutions are called "_Filters_" and behave a little weird and entirely different compared to classic folders. The best you can do is using the mentioned `source_group` command in combination with the `FOLDER` property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake: how to create visual studio filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808087/cmake-how-to-create-visual-studio-filters)