# How can I cleanly place files in the "root" filter in Visual Studio using CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

We're using CMake to generate our Visual Studio solutions. Our project is a "whole" app consisting of header files together with the source files (.h/.cpp).

We like to have the source/header files well nested under the filters in Visual Studio (the "folders" in the Solution Explorer), the same way we see them in the Windows File Explorer.

So we came up with something like this to achieve this:

```
# ...the files are added to the project in another way.

#
# Group files under filters
#
file(GLOB source_files *.cpp *.h )
file(GLOB source_files_benchmark                benchmark/*.cpp benchmark/*.h )
file(GLOB source_files_builder                  builder/*.cpp builder/*.h )
file(GLOB source_files_demo                     demo/*.cpp demo/*.h )
file(GLOB source_files_dashboard                dashboard/*.cpp dashboard/*.h )
file(GLOB source_files_gsl                      gsl/* )
file(GLOB source_files_jsonUtil2                jsonUtil2/*.cpp jsonUtil2/*.h )

source_group( ""                            FILES ${source_files} )
source_group( "benchmark"                   FILES ${source_files_benchmark} )
source_group( "builder"                     FILES ${source_files_builder} )
source_group( "dashboard"                   FILES ${source_files_dashboard} )
source_group( "demo"                        FILES ${source_files_demo} )
source_group( "gsl"                         FILES ${source_files_gsl} )
source_group( "jsonUtil2"                   FILES ${source_files_jsonUtil2} )
```

(Please note that we're using "the evil" file GLOB to generate our lists. We're aware of the risks and we found out that they were less of an inconvenience than to add new files manually; I also don't think the way we get the file list is relevant here.)

This works and we have the nice project structure when we load the project in Visual Studio.

I though I could probably improve upon this and came up with this alternative solution:

```
# Nicely put the files into "filters" in Visual Studio. We used to do this 
# manually but this way requires less work, overall. 

# Get all the files CMake knows about.
get_target_property(local_app_sources ${my_target} SOURCES)
get_target_property(local_app_headers ${my_target} HEADERS)

set(local_app_files ${local_app_sources})
list(APPEND local_app_files ${local_app_headers})

# Create two lists, one we'll use for the "root", and one we'll use for the "in 
# folders". More details below.
set(local_root_files ${local_app_files})
set(local_in_folder_files ${local_app_files})

list(FILTER local_root_files      EXCLUDE REGEX ".*/.*")
list(FILTER local_in_folder_files INCLUDE REGEX ".*/.*")

# For some reasons, CMake will place the files that are at the "root" under the 
# "Source Files" filter in Visual Studio, so we have moved those files to their 
# own list. We use the source_group(TREE command to make a nice tree with the 
# files that are under a folder, and we'll use the default version of the 
# command to place the files that are at the root into an "empty string" folder 
# (no folder), so that they'll be placed at the root. 
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${local_in_folder_files})
source_group( "" FILES ${local_root_files} )
```

I'm happy that we don't have to add new folders manually anymore. However, I find it's still a bit verbose and I'm wondering if I could achieve the same with a single call to `source_group(TREE`, without the need to split the list and put the files that are at the "root" explicit into that folder.

How can I achieve this? What am I missing?

I've tried the "PREFIX" parameter but it just put everything into that folder (I end up with `<prefix>/Source Files/src..`), and we also don't *need* a prefix.

We're using CMake 3.8.something (I know, it's old and we should upgrade... we'll get to it, someday.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution can be simplified by using `REGULAR_EXPRESSION` option of [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) instead of `FILES` option.
This will also get rid of the evil `GLOB` command.

```
source_group("benchmark" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "benchmark/.+\.(h|cpp)")
source_group("builder" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "builder/.+\.(h|cpp)")
...
```

See [CMake Regex Specification](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/string.html#regex-specification).

---

As for the `TREE` option, your solution is pretty good.
With the following minor modification, I can get the filtering behaviour as you desire, where files are filtered according to their folder name, and the ones at the root folder has no filter instead of being listed under "Source Files".

```
get_target_property(_sources my_target SOURCES)
get_target_property(_headers my_target HEADERS)

set(_files ${_sources} ${_headers})

source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${_files})
```

---

Note that it is sometimes necessary to run CMake command in a clean build environment for VS filters to take effect.
I suspect that was the reason you had to apply a workaround to the `TREE` solution.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Why not? VS filters i.e. folders in Solution Explorer are achieved by [`source_group`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) command in CMake. This answer uses `REGULAR_EXPRESSION` option which is easier than `FILES` option.

Comment: Yes, both approaches I mention in my question use source_group to put files in my filters; the second approach I mentioned allows me to not use one group per vs folder; going back to having to add a new line to the CMakeLists.txt each time I add a new source folder is not an improvement at all. I brought down the count of calls to source_group from one per folder to _two_, the question is: can I bring this down to _one_?

Comment: I see. Nice solution. I'll keep mine for future reference. You say files at root are placed under "Source Files" but I cannot reproduce that. It works fine if I provide all files to TREE command.

Comment: Which version of CMake do you use? Maybe it's only a matter of upgrading.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I am using CMake 3.23.1 but I don't think that is related to the issue. I have updated the answer.