# How to make CMake-generated Visual Studio projects capitalize the files properly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm generating a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project with CMake. Everything works fine, except that all filenames are switched to lowercase. The filenames generated by CMake globbing are properly capitalized, but when opening the resulting project in Visual Studio (or with an editor), I can see that all filenames are suddenly lowercase (even though the paths themselves are properly capitalized).

With the C++/CLI project in the same solution, it works flawlessly.

Normally, I would only see it as a minor annoyance, but saving these files through Visual Studio changes the filename on disk and, by extension, in the repository.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please give an example for what files/project types it does not work? I've tested my code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422680/how-to-set-visual-studio-filters-for-nested-sub-directory-using-cmake), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808087/cmake-how-to-create-visual-studio-filters) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645217/visual-studio-as-an-editor-for-cmake-friendly-project) with VS2015 and they all worked fine (not showing the behavior you described).

Comment: Agree with Florian. Using VS 2013 with CMake 3.0.2 having no problems with file name or path case being preserved. I suggest that you check your source code control system, if you are updating your the source code at compile time perhaps it is changing the case on you?

Comment: After rebooting my machine, it suddenly works. I have no idea what happened there.