# Winform AllowDrop not working when debugging

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, textbox

I have a small and simple Winform app which contains a Textbox with the `AllowDrop` property set to true.  I'm handling the `DragDrop` and `DragEnter` events as such:

```
Private Sub txtFile_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles txtFile.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtFile_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles txtFile.DragDrop
    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    If Not files Is Nothing AndAlso files.Length > 0 Then
        txtFile.Text = files.First()
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that the textbox will not accept a file drop when I F5 debug, instead I get the 'No' cursor.  If I end debugging and run the executable from the /bin folder, it works as expected.

Is there something specific about Visual Studio debugging which would prevent filedrops from working, or do I need to change any code for debugging?

Comment: I'm using VS Community 2013 and it allows me to drag and drop a file while running from the IDE.  You may be running into a [UAC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15226600/2330053) type problem?

Comment: I promise I searched.  It was indeed a UAC problem.  Thanks.